# JavaScript: How to "cache" a file to download, then trigger download upon request?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a web app that allows a user to "generate" an HTML email that they can download. When the user clicks the "preview" button, the form is submitted to a new window, which actually generates the html.

```
<form action="/preview" method="post" target="previewWindow" onsubmit="window.open('', 'previewWindow', 'width=660,height=800,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
    <!-- form elements go here -->
</form>
```

Then I display the HTML on the page in order to "preview" the html before actually downloading the file.

```
<!-- this is the html used in the popup window -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
    <div id="emailHtml">
        <?php echo $this->emailHtml; // the HTML that I will want to download soon ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My script has already done the work of generating the HTML since I am already displaying it on the page. Is there a way to generate an HTML file from this HTML and "cache" it so that when the user clicks the download link, it simply triggers the browser to download this content as a file without having to re-generate the html again? I'm trying not to save any files on the server if I don't need to.

Comment: No. Browser save doesn't work like that. But you don't need to save the file on the server side as you can regenerate it on the fly based on inputs? Also setting strong HTTp caching headers on the generated page may prevent the second download (not guaranteed)

Comment: The file can be saved as a base64 string and attach to any HTML element in the current page, you can read it again when you want to use/download it.?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mikko Ohtamaa's comment above, it seems that there is no way to achieve this with JavaScript. I have decided to save the file to a temp directory as a workaround. I'm still interested to hear if there is a way to do something like this without saving the file to the server.