# Downloading images that are already cached

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a web application which caches images to be downloaded.

Say you have the following html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" download="">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="Image"/>
</a>
```

When you right click on the image and click save it saves the image directly. However when you click on the link (or trigger it with javascript) it has to redownload the entire image, even though it's already in the cache.

Is there a way to save the image without having to redownload it? (Or to cache it in another way, maybe by creating a blob or data URL?)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong but I don't believe this is possible. It seems [you're not the first one to ask for something along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264557/javascript-how-to-cache-a-file-to-download-then-trigger-download-upon-reques). Unfortunately, this doesn't exactly contain a ton of helpful information - the question doesn't seem to have received sufficient attention, thought that could potentially speak to the idea that it isn't actually possible.

Comment: The only thing I can think of and I may be way off (*which is why this is a comment*) is using **HTTP2**? That way the server sends the image to the browser before the browser needs it.

Comment: Maybe cache it manually using AJAX?

Comment: @Jonasw Yeah maybe you could get the image with AJAX and put it in a blob or data URL, but then you would be affected by the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Try service worker to cache the requests:

something like this:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Pencil-ruler_icon.png" download="">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Pencil-ruler_icon.png" alt="Image"/>
    </a>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script file (test.js):

```
caches
    .open('assets')
    .then(cache => cache.addAll([
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Pencil-ruler_icon.png'
    ]))
    .then(() => 
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('cache-image.js', { scope: './' })
            .then(navigator.serviceWorker.ready)
    )
```

service worker itself (cache-image.js):

```
// this is the service worker which intercepts all http requests
self.addEventListener('fetch', function fetcher (event) {
  var request = event.request;
  // check if request 
  if (request.url.indexOf(
      'Pencil-ruler_icon.png'
    ) > -1) {
    // contentful asset detected
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        // return from cache, otherwise fetch from network
        return response || fetch(request);
      })
    );
  }
});
```